# Docker error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using `docker+machine` to run my `gitlab` ci/cd jobs.

So my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like below:

```
stages:
  - RUN_TESTS

image:
  name: docker:stable

services:
  - name: docker:dind

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""    

build-docker:
  stage: RUN_TESTS
  script:
    - echo "Running the tests..."
    - docker build -t run-tests .
```

This works totally fine with `docker:dind` image set as the `service` block as shown above.

Now here comes the fun part, I need some other packages inside the `docker:dind` image. So I wrote the `Dockerfile` as below:

```
FROM docker:dind

RUN apk update

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN apk add --update --no-cache python3 && ln -sf python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN python3 -m ensurepip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade pip setuptools

RUN apk add groff
RUN pip3 install awscli
RUN apk --purge -v del py-pip
RUN rm /var/cache/apk/*
```

So, I built the above image and pushed it into my dockerhub.

As of now, everything is cool. Image built successfully and pushed successfully.

And then I changed the `services` in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` to my new images as below:

```
services:
  - name: 199508/dind-new:latest
```

And I ran the pipeline and I get the error below.

This error I am getting below is strange:

> error during connect: Post http://docker:2375/v1.40/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&session=n6fvaaoisom3ny2cfozrlom50&shmsize=0&t=run-tests&target=&ulimits=null&version=1: dial tcp: lookup docker on : no such host

The only change I did was installing some applications/dependencies in the above `Dockerfile` but why it is not working? How come when I use `docker:dind` it is working and when I created a new `Dockerfile` with the same `docker:dind` base image and it doesn't work?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The problem you are describing is detailed in a GitLab blog post here: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I just run into this problem yesterday
The main thing is to switch to docker image version
In Your case in the Dockerfile not like here

```
FROM docker:18.09
```

And change the port:
The lines commented out are the once the didn't work for me.

```
image: 199508/dind-new:v5
services:
  # - docker:19.03.12-dind
  - docker:18.09-dind


variables:
  # Use TLS https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#tls-enabled
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  # DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
  # DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  CONTAINER_RELEASE_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
```

Comment: Hi, what are the `$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` and `$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG` and `$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` variables?

Comment: my new image name is `199508/dind-new:v5` and where I should put this?

Comment: I added your image name to the example where it should be, the service should stay the same as far as I know.

Comment: The variable you asked about are for later use not mandatory

Comment: And is there a way I can put these environmental configurations out of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` and put it somewhere in the `config.toml` for the runner?

Comment: Glad it helped you, I spend few hours yesterday on this error.

Comment: I don't know, never used self hosted gitlab runner or config.toml